# Tax by Zip Code using Expresso Store Expression Engine

Tags: e-commerce, expressionengine, expresso-store

I have a store running off of Expresso Store and Expression Engine. Currently they only have Tax based off of the state I need to run my taxes based off of the zip code (for legal purposes). Expresso Store does not offer an out of the box solution for this and I was wondering if there was anyone who has figured this out or may be able to offer any assistance?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

[Apparently](https://developers.google.com/checkout/articles/Google_Checkout_Articles_Zip_Level_Taxes) Google uses data from [these folks](http://www.taxdatasystems.com/) -- they offer db- and web service-based lookups.  The integration with Expresso is left as an exercise for the reader ;)

Answer (score 0):

At the moment you would need to write your own extension to have tax based at the zipcode level. The easiest way would be to add a new table that has zipcodes and their respective tax rate. Then with the store_order_taxes ( https://exp-resso.com/docs/extension_hooks.html#tax_hooks ) hook build an extension that checks the customers zipcode and apply the correct tax rate for their address.